# How appropriate is it for me to join in with non-work conversations, and to what degree (as contractor)?

Tags: team, contracting

I have recently jumped into the contracting/consulting world, and landed my first project with a client where I'm working full-time on-site. This means I've entered a typical office environment with a friendly team of (permanent) developers. Naturally there's office chit chat and discussion, both work related (How are you getting on? Can you explain how this works?) and non-work related (What did you think of movie X? What are you up to this weekend?)

How appropriate is it for me to join in with these non-work conversations, and to what degree? Given my position, it's costing the client more for me to be there than the permanent guys and technically the chatter isn't helping me do my job. However, it's been a few weeks and no one has pulled me up on it. Consequently I've become more comfortable in the environment and spent more time engaging with the team than I did in the first few days. (Don't misunderstand me, I'm still very much focused on the project at hand)

I'm acutely aware that my time is valuable and my output is important, but I'm also concerned if I don't 'join in' my job could be made more difficult and I might not be seen as part of the team. This feels important, as I'd like to be here for several months and if no one is getting on with me that seems unlikely.

Comment: I fear this may be subjective based on the opinion of the team manager. At the end of the day, you are in his/her team and the 'level' of engagement you have with his/her (perm) team members is up to them. Talk to your manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be doing fine. Just keep it within decent limits. In this sort of situation I'm friendly but I make sure everyone knows I'm focused on tasks so constant chit chat will not happen.

I don't initiate conversations and I don't prolong them when they peter out. At the end of the day I am a temporary outsider. So I don't really get involved with anyone in this sort of scenario. I have clients who I have worked in their offices on and off for a decade, seen their staff come and go and I'm practically a fixture in their eyes. But in reality they know nothing much about me apart from when I am actually there, non work related conversations have been basically meaningless for the decade, and although they know I have numerous other clients, most would not know who they are and I never discuss my other clients work.

Steer clear of conversations on Religion, Politics, Ethnicity, and Sex. When you do chat, keep it light and shallow (don't discuss your personal problems, or anyone else's). When the conversation is taking too long, put your 'professional' face on, and switch to something work related. They will take the hint. Do your work thoroughly and efficiently and don't get distracted.

A huge part of consulting/contracting in an environment like this for the long term, revolves around gaining the respect and trust of your clients and their staff. I've met many people over the years who have risen through the ranks and gone on to big things and liked and trusted me enough to give me more work. One chap eventually became a Govt CEO. So be polite and friendly to the lowliest grunt as well as the financial controller.

Answer (score 1):

As a contractor your limitations here should be fairly similar to a permanent employee.  Remember that integrating into the team can be key to doing a good job.  If information often flows through informal channels being an outsider could potentially cause you to miss key information.  Put in the effort to become "one of the team" but do your job and don't be a major distraction to others.  Limit it to reasonable levels, just like any employee, and you will be fine.